# How to prevent buttons from activating screen

Tags: lock-screens, buttons

When I take my Android phone from my trousers pocket the screen is often activated since any press to the search, home, back or menu button activates the screen. Of course, this is a major battery drain. Even worse - sometimes the phone takes or rejects an incoming call while being in my pocket without me noticing. 8-(

So: is there any way to prevent these buttons from activating the screen? Only the power on button should wake it up, since it is much better hidden and cannot be accidentially pressed in the pocket.

In case that matters: my phone is a LG-P500 with Android version 2.2.2

Comment: Simply do not buy LG phone the next time. Their design sucks - see similar problem here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/78241/68373

Answer (score 0):

If you did not find anything related in the settings, a solution could be to install a custom ROM (such as CyanogenMod). They often provide a much wider set of settings, and I remember having seen something like "Menu button wakes phones on/off" on some of my older devices.

Answer (score 0):

When your phone is locked and you press any key, the screen only lights up for a few seconds. Even if you accidentally press home or search, nothing will happen until you unlock it. There is no reason to have a dedicated button just for waking up the screen.

EDIT: It's about time, buddy. Get a Nexus device.

Comment: The trouble is that the erratic movement of the phone in my pocket *does* sometimes manage to unlock it via the slider. If that happens the phone sometimes shows the emergency call screen with tons of numbers pressed. The menu, search, back and home button should have no business waking up the phone - that's what the well hidden "on" button is for. :-(