# How to stop the LG phone launching preset applications when the phone is locked and inside your pocket?

Tags: applications, settings, lock-screens, buttons, lg-g2

This design concerns more LG phones, in my case it's LG G2 Mini, but it was reported also on LG D605 Optimus L9 II and probably other LG phones with the same logic.

On the back of LG G2 Mini (Android 4.4.2), there are 2 buttons, which keep being pushed in my pocket.

Unfortunately, there are applications mapped (by manufacturer setting) to the up and down buttons (some drawing notes and camera) when the phone is locked. They keep being launched unwillingly in my pocket.

I've searched through all the settings but couldn't find **how to get rid of this mapping and set the buttons' action to void in the phone-locked mode**.

My phone is rooted so I can change the system settings but don't know where it is stored.

[image: **LG G2 mini back**]

---

EDIT: In the official LG upgrade of Android (5.0.2) the problem is solved, see my answer.

Comment: How did you perform the mapping? Stock or custom firmware?

Comment: I want to **get rid** of the mapping, it's built in! It comes with the phone :(

Comment: Just a guess - Have you tried pressing and HOLDing until some sort of dialog appears to unset the mapping?

Comment: @wbogacz; pressing and holding is exactly what *launches* these stupid applications!

Comment: @Honza - correct. Their manual says 3 seconds of pressing will launch. Holding longer (to express an intentional, different intent) - Anything?

Comment: Holding longer doesn't do anything different, unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW SOLUTION:

In the official LG update of Android (5.0.2) LG finally came themselves with an option to turn off the "feature".

Settings | System | Shortcut key

[image]

---

ORIGINAL so called a "solution":

After a long research, I am answering my question by stating that in Android 4 (the original version of the phone) it does not have a proper solution.

I called to LG helpdesk as well as wrote them emails. They always answered that "It's a feature, not a bug", the buttons events are hard-coded and that I can use a protective case if I want to avoid the accidental push.

Comment: I don't know a hack, but I think the buttons are hard-coded to only work with the LG stock ROM, so I think if you flash a different ROM (Cyanogenmod for example) the buttons simply will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

"Key Plus for LG G3, G Pro, G2"
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apptuners.keyplusapp

This app works for me, but only for volume down on lg g2 mini

via http://www.reddit.com/r/lgg2/comments/2q6chq/app_key_plus_change_lg_g2_volume_key_shortcuts_to/

There is also G2 Tweaksbox but it depends on application which requires root

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.ptoti.g2_tweaksbox&hl=pl

http://forum.xda-developers.com/g2-mini/help/long-press-volume-camera-t2826540

Comment: Your solution does not work. The buttons still call the built-in apps :(

Comment: maybe something changed. I don't have this phone anymore so I can't test it